# JQuery loop through checked boxes and populate div

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-2, partial-views, checkbox

```
<div id="termSheetPopup">
    <input type="checkbox" name="SummaryInformation">Summary Information<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="SwapLegs">Swap Legs<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="AmortizationOptions">Amortization Options<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="EconomicResults">Economic Results<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="AmortizationSchedule">Amortization Schedule
</div>

<div id="printing">

</div>
```

So looking at the above code, the `termSheetPopup` is the div that I turn into my JQuery dialog. When the user clicks the dialog 'Generate' button, I want JQuery to tell me the names of all of the checkboxes that are checked (the `name` element of them), so I can use those names to populate the div `printing`. Each of those names correspond to a partial view that I want to render within the div.

Also, if you have time, how would I render a partial view dynamically using JQuery, similar to how I do it on the page within ASP.NET like this:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Indications/AmortizationSchedule.aspx", Model.Trx); %>
```

How could I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything so far in terms of getting the names with jquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var myArray = [];
$('#termSheetPopup input').is(':checked').each(function(){
      myArray.push( $(this).attr('name') );
});
```

Comment: :selected only works for option elements, need to use :checked for radios or checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

Should help.  Do what ever you need with the name in the each loop, array, append to div, etc...

```
$('#Generate').bind('click', function() {
   $('#termSheetPopup :checkbox:checked').each(function() {
      $('#printing').append($(this).attr('name')+', ');
   });
});
```

**edit:** edited for completeness, appending the names into the printing div comma separated.  Should put this into a document ready, as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('button').click(function(){
    var e = $('#termSheetPopup input:checked');
    for (i = 0; i < e.length; i++){
        $('#printing').append(e[i].name + ' ');
    }
});
```

Here is sample - http://jsfiddle.net/gorsky/AhCAW/